# Compile from different versions of Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I'm new to Fortran. I have a file written in a non-standard version of Fortran, written for the Lahey-Fujitsu compiler and using the proprietary numerical library IMSLF90 (see my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472015/identify-version-of-fortran-of-this-code-for-the-lf-compiler)). Let's call that file `test.f`. There is a function in IMSLF90 that inverts matrices. If I comment out those matrix inversions, I can compile the source with either `ifort` or `gfortran`. I do not have access to IMSLF90, and I'm looking for a way to bring in a matrix inversion function from some library. I tried with the toolbox provided in [ce-fortran.com](https://www.ce-fortran.com/toolbox/) (I new to Fortran and do not know any better).

My problem is that when I `include "toolbox.f90"` at the top of the file, and substitute `use IMSLF90` for `use toolbox` in `test.f` file (and modify the matrix inversion computation from `.i. x` to `lu_invert(x)`) , and then try to compile, the compiler complaints:

```
ifort test.f -o test.out
toolbox.f90(21): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [m]
module toolbox
^
toolbox.f90(21): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [o]
module toolbox
-^
toolbox.f90(21): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [d]
module toolbox
--^
toolbox.f90(21): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [u]
module toolbox
---^
toolbox.f90(21): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [l]
module toolbox
----^
toolbox.f90(21): error #5118: First statement in file must not be continued
module toolbox
-----^
toolbox.f90(30): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [i]
implicit none
^
toolbox.f90(30): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [m]
implicit none
-^
toolbox.f90(30): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [p]
implicit none
--^
toolbox.f90(30): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [l]
implicit none
---^
toolbox.f90(30): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [i]
implicit none
----^
toolbox.f90(33): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [p]
private
^
toolbox.f90(33): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [r]
private
-^
toolbox.f90(33): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [i]
private
--^
toolbox.f90(33): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [v]
private
---^
toolbox.f90(33): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [a]
private
----^
toolbox.f90(36): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [r]
real*8, private :: starttime_cpu
^
toolbox.f90(36): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [e]
real*8, private :: starttime_cpu
-^
toolbox.f90(36): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [a]
real*8, private :: starttime_cpu
--^
toolbox.f90(36): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [l]
real*8, private :: starttime_cpu
---^
toolbox.f90(36): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [*]
real*8, private :: starttime_cpu
----^
toolbox.f90(39): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [l]
logical, private :: tbox_seed = .true.
^
toolbox.f90(39): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [o]
logical, private :: tbox_seed = .true.
-^
toolbox.f90(39): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [g]
logical, private :: tbox_seed = .true.
--^
toolbox.f90(39): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [i]
logical, private :: tbox_seed = .true.
---^
toolbox.f90(39): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [c]
logical, private :: tbox_seed = .true.
----^
test.f(41): catastrophic error: Too many errors, exiting
compilation aborted for test.f (code 1)
```

I think what's happening is that the `include` statement at the top essentially "writes" the code in `toolbox.f90` into the main source code in `test.f`, and since they do not follow the same Fortran standard, the compiler gets confused.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Rename the file to test.f90.  If you're new to Fortran, there are 2 source code forms:  fixed-form and free-form.  Some compilers (including gfortran) use a .f extension to mean fixed-form and .f90 to mean free-form.  BTW to do matrix inversion, google LAPACK

Comment: The file `test.f` is in fixed format, while `toolbox.f90` is not. If I rename `test.f` to `test.f90` I still get some errors, though different than before. For example: the comment lines with `c` throw errors.

Comment: Given the error messages you posted and comment about comment lines starting with `c`.  Your code is neither free-form nor fixed-form.  But, we don't know because you refuse to post code.  Good luck learning how to write correct Fortran.

Comment: I'm not at liberty to post the full content of `test.f`, but if you see my previous post, referenced above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472015/identify-version-of-fortran-of-this-code-for-the-lf-compiler, you will find some sample lines. Thank you for the good wishes, always appreciate them.

Comment: Sounds as though test.f is some strange mix of free and fixed format, but as you refuse to post it's very difficult help more - can you generate another file that you can show and gives the same problems? Oh, and I agree with @evets, use LAPACK, it's free and open source, and won't tie you to a particular compiler.

Comment: If it turns out that the linked question I chose isn't suitable, then please edit the question with more detail and ping me to reopen.